# Как взять все элементы по имени класса, где css равно спец. значению?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

У меня ситуация такая. Есть меню с раскрытыми блоками. Где то блоки раскрыты, где то нет.

Я хочу взять все элементы по имени класса, в которых css("display")=="block" и применить для них .slideToggle("normal")

как это можно сделать? тут нужен цикл или можно как то одной строкой?

Вот имя класса для элементов которые я хочу взять: navpanelelement-content

Comment: [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) Вам в помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$( ".navpanelelement-content" ).each(function( i ) {
 if($(this).css("display") == "block"){
  $(this).slideToggle("normal");
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:block;">adwwdawd</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:inline-block;">awdwadwad</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:block;">awdawdwada</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:inline-block;">wdawdwad</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:block;">awdawdawd</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:inline-block;">awdwdawd</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:block;">awdawdawda</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:inline-block;">wdadaw</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

По сути, верный ответ уже дан, но почему бы и такой вариант не предложить (по идее они одинаково работают в плане скорости):

```js
$( ".navpanelelement-content" )
  .filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("display") === "block";
  })
  .slideToggle("normal");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:block;">adwwdawd</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:inline-block;">awdwadwad</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:block;">awdawdwada</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:inline-block;">wdawdwad</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:block;">awdawdawd</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:inline-block;">awdwdawd</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:block;">awdawdawda</div>
<div class="navpanelelement-content" style="display:inline-block;">wdadaw</div>
```

Comment: не должны одинаково: у тебя один проход по полной коллекции для фильтрации, и второй проход по оставшейся коллекции с вызовом slideToggle. В соседнем ответе: один проход по полной коллекции.

Comment: @Grundy, хмхм, никогда не задумывался на самом деле, что `slideToggle` ещё раз проходится по всей коллекции и применяет к каждому элементу. Но ответ думаю имеет смысл оставить, особенно с подобным комментарием ибо имеет место быть. Btw, думал твой подход "он как минимум короче на 1 символ" применим к любой оптимизации, но видимо нет xDDD